# PL/SQL-> inserting 500 users to a table from excel

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

We have a Oracle table which consists of following columns:      user,code,date,number,origin.eg:

```
|user, code, date, number, origin| 
|--------------------------------|  
|stah,  LK,  10-1,  20091,  WEST |   
|hats,  LJ,  12-2,  30001,  ESTA |
```

This table already has 1000 users. Now we want to add another 500 new users to this table and also grant all those 500 users same code->{'LD','LM','MK',CK'}.i.e each user should have same code (And date,number,origin can be null).

I have 500 users in excel. Can someone help me to figure out how to insert these into a table?

Comment: A) Use Excel VBA to generate your insert statements or B) Save Excel document as csv then use SQL*Loader to bulk load the data or C) Save Excel document as csv and then use SQL Developer to import the csv into your table.

Comment: If you have an Oracle Database, install APEX. Then build a web application from your Excel file. Then give access to the app to your users - the db will get updated auto-magically.

Comment: I have only users on Excel.records of code column i need to enter manually. So how is that possible? –

Answer (score 1):

Build your script manually in excel by using formulars:

```
user    code    date    number  origin  skript
stah    LK      10-1    20091   West    =CONCAT("INSERT INTO mytable values(""";A2;"""";""";B2;"""";""";C2;"""";""";D2;"""";""";E2;"""";");")
hats    LJ      12-2    30001   ESTA    INSERT INTO mytable values("hats"";B2;"";"12-2"";D2;"";"ESTA");
```

First row shows formular - second shows the result..

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQL Developer to import data from spreadsheet into table. Look here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Import_Export/sqldev3.0_import_export.htm#t3

Answer (score 0):

- You can use free data migration tool `PDI` which is very helpful and
  manageable
- You can schedule it by using windows or linux scheduler

here is a tutorial link how it migrate excel to oracle

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDxdy_8mOa0

Comment: I have only users on Excel.records  of  code column i need to enter manually. So how is that possible?